# Using Info Path with New SharePoint List

Tags: sharepoint-online, infopath

I have created a New custom list in SharePoint. When I try to open the form up in InfoPath, using the 'SharePoint List' form, copy and paste the new URL into the field and double click my New site... the form that comes up is the form I previously used for another SP list.

```
 How do I get the NEW SP site default form to populate?
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using SharePoint Online, consider using Forms, PowerApps, and/or Flow.  Infopath is not supported in SPO. It is supported up to SP 2016 on-prem and there is a persistent rumor that it might be resurrected for some sort of support for SP 2019 on prem (in lieu of Forms/Flow/PowerApps).

Comment: My apologies, I clicked the wrong #Tag... I am using SharePoint 2016.